# How to extract rows with the given sequence of values for 2 subsequent columns?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I find the sequence of values `AAA`, `BBB` among columns `COL_1`, `COL_2`, `COL_3`, ....,`COL_X` (where `X` is some number, e.g. 200, so enumeration is not a good solution)?

For example, if there is a dataframe `df`, then the row 1 and 4 should be the output:

```
df=
ID    COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4
1     AAA     BBB     CCC     DDD
2     DDD     AAA     CCC     BBB
3     BBB     AAA     DDD     CCC
4     CCC     AAA     BBB     DDD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join the relevant columns of row as string and then search for `AAA,BBB` pattern.

```
In [152]: df.filter(regex='COL_').apply(lambda x: 'AAA,BBB' in ','.join(x), axis=1)
Out[152]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

If you numeric values, convert them to string using `map`

```
In [166]: df.apply(lambda x: 'AAA,BBB' in ','.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)
Out[166]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

In [175]: df[df.apply(lambda x: 'AAA,BBB' in ','.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)]
Out[175]:
   ID COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4
0   1   AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD
3   4   CCC   AAA   BBB    DD
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how to get rows, not `True` or `False`?

Comment: Also, I get an error `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found', u'occurred at inde`

Comment: Are you sure, you are working on the same sample data? All `COL_` columns are expected to be strings.

Comment: I have both numeric values and strings in my real dataset. Sorry for not mentioning it. Could you please add the solution for numeric values?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. The only thing is that it returns `True` and `False`. How to filter out all `False` rows in order to see only the rows corresponding to `True`?

Comment: Updated it, that should do.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through all columns shifted by one and zipped in pairs:

```
def func(x):
    return any(x1 == 'AAA' and x2 == 'BBB' for x1, x2 in 
               zip(x.slice_shift(1), x.slice_shift(-1)))

print(df[df.apply(func, axis=1)])
```

For this dataframe:

```
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4  COL_5
ID                               
1    AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD     10
2    DDD   AAA   CCC   BBB     20
3    BBB   AAA   DDD   CCC     30
4    CCC   AAA   BBB   DDD     40
```

the output looks like this:

```
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3 COL_4  COL_5
ID                               
1    AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD     10
4    CCC   AAA   BBB   DDD     40
```

The `x.slice_shift(1)` is equivalent to `x[1:]` but does not copy the data.